# JS - Доработать функцию переноса

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, очень слаб в JS, нужна помощь, есть скрипт

```js
var useritems = [];
var botitems = [];

function addTrade(items, dest) {
  if (items.length < 10) {
    items.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
    $(this).appendTo(dest);
  }
}

function removetrade(items, dest) {
  items.splice(items.indexOf($(this).attr('data-id')), 1);
  $(this).appendTo(dest);
}

function addRemoveInit(items, src, dest) {
  $(src).on('click', '.item', function() {
    addTrade.call(this, items, dest);
  });
  $(dest).on('click', '.item', function() {
    removetrade.call(this, items, src);
  });
}
addRemoveInit(useritems, '.inventoryload', '.tradehave');
addRemoveInit(botitems, '.botinventoryload', '.tradewant');

function tradesend() {
  if (useritems.length > 0) {
    var data_post = reduceItems(botitems, 'h', reduceItems(useritems, 'w', {}));
    console.log(data_post);
  }
}

function reduceItems(items, prefix, start) {
  return items.reduce(function(acc, el, index) {
    acc[prefix + (index + 1)] = el;
    return acc;
  }, start);
}
```

```css
.inventoryload {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.botinventoryload {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.tradewant {
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.tradehave {
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.inv {
  float: left;
}
.trade {
  float: left;
}
.item {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inv">
  <div class="inventoryload">
    <p class="item" data-id="1111">1111</p>
    <p class="item" data-id="1251">1251</p>
    <p class="item" data-id="4444">4444</p>
  </div>
  <div class="botinventoryload">
    <p class="item" data-id="3251">3251</p>
    <p class="item" data-id="8018">8018</p>
    <p class="item" data-id="6543">6543</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="trade">
  <div class="tradehave">
  </div>
  <div class="tradewant">
  </div>
</div>
<button onClick="tradesend();" id="button">Обменять</button>
```

Он добавляет в массив JS значение при переносе из левого поля в правое сверху и так же снизу, но появилась потребность делать обратное, тоесть при нажатии кнопки "Изменить", этот массив снова воспроизводился (подробнее: При переносе и нажатии "Добавить" на одной странице- эти поля заносятся в Базу Данных, а на другой странице отображаются те же поля, но преметы внутри достаются из обычной Базы Данных, а нужно, что бы там была кнопка "Изменить" и они бы оставались на местах, но при этом уже занесены в массив перенесенных (или нет) предметов).

Вот код 2 страницы и о где собственно проблема:

```js
var useritems = [];
var botitems = [];

function addTrade(items, dest) {
  if (items.length < 10) {
    items.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
    $(this).appendTo(dest);
  }
}

function removetrade(items, dest) {
  items.splice(items.indexOf($(this).attr('data-id')), 1);
  $(this).appendTo(dest);
}

function addRemoveInit(items, src, dest) {
  $(src).on('click', '.item', function() {
    addTrade.call(this, items, dest);
  });
  $(dest).on('click', '.item', function() {
    removetrade.call(this, items, src);
  });
}
addRemoveInit(useritems, '.inventoryload', '.tradehave');
addRemoveInit(botitems, '.botinventoryload', '.tradewant');

function tradesend() {
  if (useritems.length > 0) {
    var data_post = reduceItems(botitems, 'h', reduceItems(useritems, 'w', {}));
    console.log(data_post);
  }
}

function reduceItems(items, prefix, start) {
  return items.reduce(function(acc, el, index) {
    acc[prefix + (index + 1)] = el;
    return acc;
  }, start);
}
```

```css
.inventoryload {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.botinventoryload {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.tradewant {
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.tradehave {
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.inv {
  float: left;
}
.trade {
  float: left;
}
.item {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 2px;
}
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script><style type="text/css">.as-console-wrapper { position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; max-height: 150px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; border-top: 1px solid #000; display: none; }
.as-console { background: #e9e9e9; border: 1px solid #ccc; display: table; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
.as-console-row { display: table-row; font-family: monospace; font-size: 13px; }
.as-console-row:after { display: table-cell; padding: 3px 6px; color: rgba(0,0,0,.35); border: 1px solid #ccc; content: attr(data-date); vertical-align: top; }
.as-console-row + .as-console-row > * { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
.as-console-row-code { width: 100%; white-space: pre-wrap; padding: 3px 5px; display: table-cell; font-family: monospace; font-size: 13px; vertical-align: middle; }
.as-console-error:before { content: 'Error: '; color: #f00; }
.as-console-assert:before { content: 'Assertion failed: '; color: #f00; }
.as-console-info:before { content: 'Info: '; color: #00f; }
.as-console-warning:before { content: 'Warning: '; color: #e90 }
@-webkit-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@-moz-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@-ms-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
.as-console-row-code, .as-console-row:after { -webkit-animation: flash 1s; -moz-animation: flash 1s; -ms-animation: flash 1s; animation: flash 1s; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inv">
  <div class="inventoryload"></div>
  <div class="botinventoryload"></div>
</div>
<div class="trade">
  <div class="tradehave">
  <p class="item" data-id="1111">1111</p></div>
  <div class="tradewant">
  <p class="item" data-id="3251">3251</p><p class="item" data-id="8018">8018</p></div></div>
<button onclick="tradesend();" id="button">Изменить</button>
<div class="as-console-wrapper"><div class="as-console">
```

Вот код, когда уже итемы перенесены в другое поле, если посмотреть в консоль, по сравнению с прошлым примером, то там нет массива тех итемов что справа, вот в этом главная проблема, нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки массивы как-то воспроизводились

Comment: Простите, может я идиот, но я не очень понял вашей проблемы..

Comment: @Yuri смотрите, вы код глянули? Если да, то вот, что делает скрипт, я нажимаю добавить и массивы верхнего и нижнего блоков с итемами вносятся в базу, а на другой странице, с таким же CSS, просто отображаются с теми же предметами но уже из базы данных (ну типо созданные), а надо, чтобы их можно было изменить, тоесть рядом должна быть кнопка, нажимаешь и те итемы, что из базы, уже можно перемещать обратно в левое поле и не потерять массив тех предметов, что справа (так как я смог реализовать обычный перенос подменяя теги на те, что в скрипте и все, а массив то получается начинался с 0)

Comment: Т.е. на странице, где подгружаются добавленные итемы, переносишь поля из правого поля в левое, нажимаешь изменить и в базу вносится изменённый массив уже с изменённым списком итемов? Или как? :)

Comment: @Yuri неет) ну вот смотри мы разобрались уже что есть 2 страницы и  одна нам не нужна (где мы создаем "форму" не нужна, а есть, где мы ее отображаем). Перейдем ко второй, там отображаются те же 4 квадратика в блоке (как и на той, где создаем), только отображаются раз 5 например (если ты создал 5 вариантов "форм"), и в каждой разные комбинации итемов, и вот представь с ними ничего нельзя сделать, они как есть так и есть, а нужно их изменять, тоесть превращать одну выбранную форму в ту, что на первой странице, если надо, могу сайт в какое нибудь ЛС скинуть, чтобы понял о чем я)

Comment: Ты есть в `vk`, `fackebook` или `telegram`? В моём профиле ссылки на мои страницы в соц. сетях

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы так хотели?

```js
var useritems = [];
var botitems = [];

$(function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < $('.tradehave').find('.item').length; i++){
     useritems.push($('.tradehave').find('.item').eq(i).attr('data-id'));
  };
  for(var i = 0; i < $('.tradewant').find('.item').length; i++){
    botitems.push($('.tradewant').find('.item').eq(i).attr('data-id'));
  };
});

function addTrade(items, dest) {
  if (items.length < 10) {
    items.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
    $(this).appendTo(dest);
  }
}

function removetrade(items, dest) {
  items.splice(items.indexOf($(this).attr('data-id')), 1);
  $(this).appendTo(dest);
}

function addRemoveInit(items, src, dest) {
  $(src).on('click', '.item', function() {
    addTrade.call(this, items, dest);
  });
  $(dest).on('click', '.item', function() {
    removetrade.call(this, items, src);
  });
}
addRemoveInit(useritems, '.inventoryload', '.tradehave');
addRemoveInit(botitems, '.botinventoryload', '.tradewant');

function tradesend() {
  if (useritems.length > 0) {
    var data_post = reduceItems(botitems, 'h', reduceItems(useritems, 'w', {}));
    console.log(data_post);
  }
}

function reduceItems(items, prefix, start) {
  return items.reduce(function(acc, el, index) {
    acc[prefix + (index + 1)] = el;
    return acc;
  }, start);
}
```

```css
.inventoryload {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.botinventoryload {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.tradewant {
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.tradehave {
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.inv {
  float: left;
}
.trade {
  float: left;
}
.item {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 2px;
}
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script><style type="text/css">.as-console-wrapper { position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; max-height: 150px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; border-top: 1px solid #000; display: none; }
.as-console { background: #e9e9e9; border: 1px solid #ccc; display: table; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
.as-console-row { display: table-row; font-family: monospace; font-size: 13px; }
.as-console-row:after { display: table-cell; padding: 3px 6px; color: rgba(0,0,0,.35); border: 1px solid #ccc; content: attr(data-date); vertical-align: top; }
.as-console-row + .as-console-row > * { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
.as-console-row-code { width: 100%; white-space: pre-wrap; padding: 3px 5px; display: table-cell; font-family: monospace; font-size: 13px; vertical-align: middle; }
.as-console-error:before { content: 'Error: '; color: #f00; }
.as-console-assert:before { content: 'Assertion failed: '; color: #f00; }
.as-console-info:before { content: 'Info: '; color: #00f; }
.as-console-warning:before { content: 'Warning: '; color: #e90 }
@-webkit-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@-moz-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@-ms-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
.as-console-row-code, .as-console-row:after { -webkit-animation: flash 1s; -moz-animation: flash 1s; -ms-animation: flash 1s; animation: flash 1s; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inv">
  <div class="inventoryload"></div>
  <div class="botinventoryload"></div>
</div>
<div class="trade">
  <div class="tradehave">
  <p class="item" data-id="1111">1111</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tradewant">
  <p class="item" data-id="3251">3251</p><p class="item" data-id="8018">8018</p>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="tradesend();" id="button">Изменить</button>
<div class="as-console-wrapper"><div class="as-console">
```